# Show summary in the footer row of vaadin-grid

Tags: polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

I am using polymer 2.0 and along with it vaadin-grid. In my application I want to show the number of records from the grid in the footer row. I could get the footer row but somehow contents in the footer row is getting repeated however I want to show the summary just once. Please find my code below. 
  `

```
 <vaadin-grid id="grid"
               items="[[ filteredData ]]"
             multi-sort
             column-reordering-allowed
             active-item="{{ selectedItem }}">

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ selectedColumns ]]" as="column">
    <table>
      <vaadin-grid-column resizable flex-grow="1">
        <template class="header">
          <vaadin-grid-sorter path="name">
            <span>[[ column.name ]]</span>
          </vaadin-grid-sorter>
        </template>
        <template>
          <div>[[ getColumnData( column.path, item ) ]]</div>
        </template>
        <template  class="footer">
          <td colspan="12">footer</div>
        </template>
      </vaadin-grid-column>
    </table>
  </template>   
 </vaadin-grid>
```

I have to show the content of the footer row just once. Here in the example, it is appearing for multiple times. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try also `vaadin-grid` element instead `dom-repeat` inside in order to use vaadin `footer-cell` class.

Comment: @HakanC, I have already used 'vaadin-grid'  element above. Could you please give me some example snippet? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was just to add a div after the grid:

The end of the grid like so

`</vaadin-grid>
<div>Number Of Record: [[_count]]</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
      <vaadin-grid-column resizable flex-grow="1">
        <template class="header">
          <vaadin-grid-sorter path="name">
            <span>[[ column.name ]]</span>
          </vaadin-grid-sorter>
        </template>
        <template>
          <div>[[ getColumnData( column.path, item ) ]]</div>
        </template>
      </vaadin-grid-column>
    </template>
    <template class="footer">
      Number of Records: [[...property or function]]
    </template>


  </vaadin-grid-column-group>
</vaadin-grid>
```